# Visual Studio Code на Linux\OpenSuse при запуске консольного приложения выходит сообщение, как отключить?

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-code

При запуске консольного приложения выдаёт сообщение:

> You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with Visual
> Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software to help
> you develop and test your applications.

Оно, вроде бы не мешает читать вывод, но мне хотелось бы его убрать. Так как впервые запускаю не monodevelop C# проект под Linux, то не знаю где искать, посмотрел где мог, в `launch.json` и настройках VSC, но не нашёл подобного.

[image: вывод в консоль]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Связанный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247398/how-to-disable-message-you-may-only-use-the-microsoft-net-core-debugger

Предлагается сделать следующее

Открыть `.vscode/launch.json` в проекте

Изменить настройки `console` на `integratedTerminal`

было: `"console": "internalConsole",`

стало: `"console": "integratedTerminal",`

сохраняем и пробуем.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но, к сожалению, спустя два с половиной года уже не могу его проверить, потому что не использую эти инструменты

Comment: а я только понял, что оно было так давно задано...

Comment: Забавно, что на английской версии аналогичный вопрос появился спустя год и сразу получил ответ, а на русской версии стака только на основе того ответа)

Comment: @SergeyK. ага. Учитывая тот факт, что ответ лежит на поверхности